# Boolean Difference not acting as expected

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm trying model and render a ring in blender.
I obtained my model with a cube on which I applied the following modifiers

[image]

I need it to be "empty" on the inside. So I duplicated my model (Shift+D) and scaled it by 0.9. I got this:
[image] [image] (not visualized correctly, but the whole thing is there)

When I try to boolean diff the larger with the smaller I get this:
[image]

Which is the smaller ring, which should in theory create the negative space on the larger ring's inside.
What I get though is the smaller ring with that weird checkered selection, and no space on the inside of the larger ring, which, in fact, disapperars.

Can anybody provide any help on this?
Is there a way to do this keeping my modifiers on the larger ring?

It's not the first time I encounter problems with boolean differnce, so any explanation on why it behaves like this is greatly appreciated :)

Thanks in advance :)

*Edit*: [Attached Blender File](http://torels.tk/dl/DIFF.blend)

*Edit2*: **Half solved**. Answer in comments. I still would like to figure out a way to merge two edge loops of a curved cube. It's actually the same cube (with one corner in 0,0,0), mirrored X,Y, and curved along a Circle. See below image for a better explanation

[image]

Comment: Are you sure both meshes are manifold and you are using the bool modifier right?

Comment: @Jerryno what is manifold? (or mainfold, not sure if that's a typo or the actual word. Either way I ignore its meaning)

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry If the meshes would be non-manifold the bool modifier wouldn't work at all, can you try your setup on some simple cubes if its right or give the .blend file so people can investigate?

Comment: Ok, tried it with a simple-subdivided cube with a curve modifier along a BezierCircle.
It's giving the same problem: THE FINAL EDGE LOOPS AREN'T MERGED.
It works once I merge them. This implies I applied my modifiers though.

Is there a way of merging the edge loop to its reflection?

Comment: Try to enable the Clipping option in the Mirror modifier. Can you post a screenshot of the modifier stack expanded? This question is hard to answer, too many possibilities what might be wrong..

Comment: clipping not working 'cause it's the same face/edge-loop really.
I don't know if it's _even_ theoretically possible.